# hapi.js: How to retrieve a very large dataset from MongoDB as a stream and then pipe that data to the response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, hapi.js

I am using hapi.js v17.2.0 and mongo driver v3.0.6.

I need to retrieve data from MongoDB (possibly tens of millions of documents) in the form of a stream and then pipe that data to the response as each chunk of data comes in from Mongo. I have been looking all over and reading everything I can find, but I still cannot figure out how to do this in hapi v17.

Please help. Thank you in advance!